# Want to make the blink forever until I press OFF in nodemcu

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, nodemcu, adafruit

I am testing a nodeMCU with Adafruit io for iot. I made a simple blink.But the blink is not working.I want to make the blink in a loop so that when I pass MQTT OFF command it will stop working.

```
#include <Adafruit_MQTT.h>            //Adafruit MQTT Libraries
#include <Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h>     //
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>              //ESP8266 Wi-Fi libraries

#define relayPin 16
```

void setup():

```
void setup() 
{pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);
  WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  mqtt.subscribe(&onoffbutton); // Setup MQTT subscription for onoff feed.
}
```

and this is the loop

```
 void loop() 
    {
       MQTT_connect();
       Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe *subscription;
        while ((subscription = mqtt.readSubscription(5000))) 
      {
        if (subscription == &onoffbutton) {
          Serial.print(F("Got: "));
          Serial.println((char *)onoffbutton.lastread);
          String response = (char*)onoffbutton.lastread; //converts the received ON or OFF to string to compare in the if-else statement
          Serial.println(response);
          if (response == "ON")
          {
            digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
          }
          else if(response == "OFF")
          {
            digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which pin is "relayPin" both on the ESP chip itself and what does it connect to?  What evidence do you have that your program has actually been loaded?  Is the LED under program control or something that blinks all by itself, like one for an on-board battery charger in a random ESP8266 module I have around here somewhere.

Comment: relayPin is **16**.I want to make the blink forever until I press OFF. But every time it needs to input separately.

Comment: Pin 16 of what?   And is that where the LED is connected?   Perhaps find a picture of your board and annotate it with an indication of the pin in question and the LED in question.  If the LED is off-board, show the circuitry supporting it.

Comment: Your question title suggests you cannot stop the blinking, while the body text suggests that it does not blink at all.  What is your question?  What is the behaviour of the code? How does that differ from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: sorry, I fixed the title

Comment: Fixed the title, but not  the question.  You appear to have some debug output.  Help us out here perhaps by including that in your question.  That is to say are you getting the expected ON/OFF MQTT messages but no blinking, or are you not getting the messages?  **Again:** What is your question? What is the behaviour of the code? How does that differ from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: I getting the expected ON/OFF MQTT messages but no blinking.

Comment: As I said: Include that information in the question.  I am trying to help you here.  Your debug demonstrates the MQTT working, but not `digitalWrite()` - could be not initialised, wrong pin, hardware fault, no power - how can we tell?  Have you tried just switching the light on or off to check that just the statements `digitalWrite(16, LOW);` and  `digitalWrite(16, HIGH);` work?  That is to say break it down to fundamental elements and verify them.  Perhaps then put debug output in the ON/OFF blocks to see if that code is even running.  If response is neither ON nor OFF, nothing will happen.

Comment: You've configured the pin in `setup()` presumably?  You are asking us to work with only a fraction of the information available to you for debugging.  As such you are unlikely to get an answer that is anything other then a guess at best.

Comment: is there any way I can put the `if (response == "ON")
          {
            digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
          }` in the loop. and it will break when I will give MQTT value off ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Edit your question rather then posting code in comments.  SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: I edited the question and gave the `setup()` code @Clifford

Comment: OK, there is a lot of stuff there that you need to discount.  If the `loop()` contains nothing but the four lines in the "ON" block, does it blink?  If not then you have seriously over-complicated your question and we are back to: _not initialised, wrong pin, hardware fault, no power_.  Is the output really a relay?  Do you have power on the load side, what kind of load are you driving?  Is this really a hardware rather than a software problem?  If it is a mechanical really, can you really drive it that fast?

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information for a real answer, so this is rather instruction on the debugging you should already have done and described in your question.

You need to work out what amongst all of that code is not working.

Start with the simplest possible blinking implementation (deliberately slow):

```
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); 
  delay(1000);                
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); 
  delay(1000);                
}
```

If that does not work, you have discounted all the MQTT stuff at least.

If it does work, the code you have will do nothing if the response is neither "ON" nor "OFF" because your code requires one or the other, when in fact you are only interested on "OFF" so change to (again deliberately slow):

```
      if( response == "OFF" )
      {
        Serial.println( "Asserting OFF" );
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println( "BLINKING" );
        digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
      }
```

Now if that blinks but you cannot switch it off, then "OFF" is not the response you are getting, or possibly it is transient and is not maintained indefinitely, in which case you need a static variable to latch the response.  Observe the serial output to see what path the code takes on each `loop()` iteration.